# How to go to a url which is parent to a url where angular config is defined

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, angularjs, angular-routing

let me tell about my app: I m trying to build a webpage using node and angular. on / (root) url i m providing form for sign up and login. i didnt use angular here. after successfully logged in i m loading angular scripts and configuration file on /home. here is my configuration file for angular:

```
window.app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
    function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
        $routeProvider.
        when('/profile', {
            templateUrl: '/views/account.html',

        }).
        when('/edit', {
            templateUrl: '/views/edit.html',

        }).
        when('/home', {
            templateUrl: 'views/index.html'
        }).
        when('/signout', {
            templateUrl: 'views/signout.html'
            //on this view i load a controller which submits a form to /signout
        }).

        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/home'
        });
    }
]);
```

on server side routing:

```
app.get('/',function(){
      res.render('index',{
         user: req.user? req.user:'guest'
    });
});
app.post('/login',function(){
         //if success redirect to /home
         //if fails redirect to /
});
app.get('/signout',function(){
         //signing out the user here...and redirects to /
});
app.get('/home',function(req,res){
    res.render('users/home',{
      user: req.user? req.user:'guest',
      message: req.flash('error')

    })
  }); 
app.get('/profile',function(req,res){
    res.render('users/home',{
      user: req.user? req.user: 'guest',
      message: req.flash('error')

    })
  });
  app.get('/edit',function(req,res){
    res.render('users/home',{
      user: req.user? req.user:'guest',
      message: req.flash('error')

    })
  });
```

now here is the problem. suppose i m in /home url. this page contains a link landing page if i click this link angular redirects me to /home instead of /. how can i remove this problem? help plz :(

Comment: In app configuration no path is specified as '/' also in otherwise '/home' is specified thus you are redirected to /home, try to configure '/' path in configuration

Answer (score 0):

By this definition in your configuration you are telling angular to redirect to `/home`:

```
...
        when('/signout', {
            templateUrl: 'views/signout.html'
        }).

        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/home'
        });
```

If you want the default to be `/`, change it to:

```
...
        when('/signout', {
            templateUrl: 'views/signout.html'
        }).

        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
```

Comment: sorry. forgot to add here signout details.plz check out. i added now. well i tried redirect '/'. if i do that. i obviously redirect to / but the problem is this request is not going to server. it just show blank where i loaded the ng-view..the header remains same.

Comment: So, if the login fails, you redirect to `/` on the server.  Why not redirect back to `/login` on the server?

Comment: my login or signup form is on `/` . user can only post on `/login` . if success `/home` is loaded and angular configuration starts. otherwise redirect him to `/` with error message

Comment: Hmmm, how do you land on the `/` page to begin with?

Comment: writing `localhost` on the browser

Comment: And angular does not pick up the first request to `localhost`? Correct?  Try to take out the `otherwise` clause in your routing altogether.

Comment: i tried that too..it just produce the same result...angular prevent the get request to server if i click any link. it just change the url location to `/`. no ng-view is loaded. how should angular suppose to pickup `/` ? bcoz i loaded the configuration file on `/home` :( i have to do that :(

Comment: Maybe, you should integrate the login panel into `ng-view` for the route `/`?  Then, you won't have to bounce back and forth.

Comment: well i did that to. but my website supporting google/facebook/linkedin authentication. for this reason i have to send request to /auth/facebook or /auth/google

Comment: Right. Maybe that is a better question to ask. OAuth with routing.  I haven't had to do it myself.  Good luck!

Comment: :( :( :( :( :( :( :( :(